# Register UrlHelper using Unity Dependency injection

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, dependency-injection, unity-container

How to register UrlHelper using Unity (Dependency Injection). we need that object to construct Dynamic paths in a domain object.

Answer (score 4):

Wrap the UrlHelper and write your interface with the desired methods.

Then register a factory class:

```
container.RegisterType<IUrlFactory, UrlFactory>();
```

With the interface:

```
public interface IUrlFactory
{
    IUrlWrapper Create();
}
```

And then in the implementation you can do:

```
class UrlFactory : IUrlFactory
{
    public IUrlWrapper Create()
    {
        var context = new HttpContextWrapper(HttpContext.Current);
        var routeData = RouteTable.Routes.GetRouteData(context);
        return new UrlWrapper(new UrlHelper(new RequestContext(context, routeData)));
    }
}
```

And when you want to write a test to mock the url you can do something like this (MOQ used):

```
var urlMock = new Mock<IUrlWrapper>();
urlMock.Setup(x => x.GetSubDomain()).Returns(string.Empty);

var urlFactoryMock = new Mock<IUrlFactory>();
urlFactoryMock.Setup(x => x.Create()).Returns(_urlMock.Object);
```